# How to approximately compute the infinite sum of inverses of products of consecutive primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, approximation

Let
$$S = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_i p_{i+1}},$$ 
where $p_i$ denotes the $i$-th prime number.

How to approximately calculate $S$? Is there a way of quickly calculating the first one/two/three digits of $S$, without resorting to computer programs? (but using calculators is allowed)

EDIT: replaced notation $\pi(i)$ with $p_i$. Added note that using calculators is allowed, but computer programs not.

Comment: Why would anybody want to do that? BTW, it's customary in number theory to denote by $\pi(n)$ the number of primes $\le n$, so you risk to confuse your reader. What do you mean with "simulation"? Just generate primes up to some threshold $N$ and add the reciprocals of the products of consecutive primes. The result will be accurate with an error of no more than $1/N$. You can also do that with pencil and paper for $N=1000$, say, if you don't like computers, there are only 168 primes in that range.

Comment: Up to $100\,000-$th the sum is $0.30109\quad$ All digits are correct. The problem is that there is no way,as far as I can tell, to know in advance the quality of the approximation we get.

Comment: Well, this was a question on a test, and it was phrased as follows: is $S$ closer to 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, or 0.5? Use of calculator was allowed, so I quickly calculated that it is at least 0.3. Rate of convergence indicated, that 0.3 should be the right answer. But I was unsure how to show this. I guess that I should have estimated the maximum possible remainder term from above to prove that the sum cannot exceed 0.34.

Comment: In number theory $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime and $\pi(x)$ is the prime-counting function (the prime number theorem being $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$, equivalently $p_n \sim n \log n$, and the Riemann zeta function is $\zeta(s) = \prod_n \frac{1}{1-p_n^{-s}}$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some observations: the standard notation for the $k$-th prime is $p_{k}$ or $q_{k}$. The symbol $\pi\left(k\right)$ usually represents the counting function of primes up to $k$, i.e., $$\pi\left(k\right)=\sum_{p\leq k}1,\,p\mathrm{\,is\,a\,prime\,number}.$$ Assuming that with the symbol $\pi\left(k\right)$ you intend $p_{k}$, you may observe that $$\sum_{k\geq n}\frac{1}{p_{k}p_{k+1}}\leq\sum_{k\geq n}\frac{p_{k+1}-p_{k}}{p_{k}p_{k+1}}=\sum_{k\geq n}\left(\frac{1}{p_{k}}-\frac{1}{p_{k+1}}\right)=\frac{1}{p_{n}}$$ and since [we know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities) that $$p_{n}>n\log\left(n\log\left(n\right)\right)-n,\,n\geq2$$ we get $$S<\sum_{k\leq n-1}\frac{1}{p_{k}p_{k+1}}+\frac{1}{n\log\left(n\log\left(n\right)\right)-n}$$ so taking, for example, $n=11$, we obtain $$S<\sum_{k\leq10}\frac{1}{p_{k}p_{k+1}}+\frac{1}{11\log\left(11\log\left(11\right)\right)-11}\approx \color{red}{0.334}.$$

Comment: I would also mention the [prime-gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) (estimating $p_{k+1}-p_k$ being a hard problem)

Comment: This is perfect, allows one to obtain upper bounds quite fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can compute a few terms and then bound the remaining terms by
$$
\sum_{i=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi(i) \pi(i+1)} \le \sum_{i=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \sum_{i=n}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{i+1} \right) = \frac{1}{n}.
$$