# $ \frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{5\cdot 7}+\frac{1}{11\cdot 13}+\frac{1}{17\cdot 19}+\dots = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_{2k-1}\cdot p_{2k}}=16/75$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Basel problem solved by Euler is:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6} 
$$
Now , I want to know what is 
$$
\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{5\cdot 7}+\frac{1}{11\cdot 13}+\frac{1}{17\cdot 19}+\frac{1}{23\cdot 29}+ \dots = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_{2k-1}\cdot p_{2k}} == ?
$$
where $p_k$ is the $k$'th prime. I tried writing a script

```
    <script async>
const primes_first_n10000=[null,2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13,..., 104711, 104717, 104723, 104729];
let p =primes_first_n10000,n=800;
let a=1n,b=6n;
let t=6n;
for (let k=3;k<n;k+=2) {
    t=BigInt(p[k]*p[k+1])
    console.log(t)
    a=a*t+b
    b*=t;   
}
//console.log(a,'/',b/15n);
//  a/(b/15)===3.2===16/5 ?
console.log(a/16n,'---',b/75n);
    </script>
```

I guess that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_{2k-1}\cdot p_{2k}}=\frac{16}{75}$ , however I'm not sure!
Could you tell me the answer: what does the sum converge to?

```
#sagemath code
    var('k')
    #s=sum(1/k^2, k, 1, oo);print(s)
    s= sum(N(1/(nth_prime(k)*nth_prime(k+1)),100) for k in range(1,80000,2))
    print(N(s,100),N(pi/s,100))
    print(N(pi/15,100))
    print(N(s*15,100))

    Out: (0.21042571723113630717490968408, 14.929699159057624632476407160)
    0.20943951023931954923084289222
    3.1563857584670446076236452612
```

Comment: Being a user for over $9$ years , we expect you to properly format your question before posting.

Comment: As @TheDemonix_Hermit said, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for help on MathJax

Comment: I'm a programmer,so I think some text like 1/(2*3)+1/(5*7)+1/(11*13)+1/(17*19)+1/(23*29)+... == sum(1/(p[2k-1]*p[2k]), k, 1, oo) is better than Latex!

Comment: I really don't like Latex, MathJax ..., they are not math but symbol!

Comment: But the rest of Math.stackexchange likes MathJax/LaTeX...

Comment: @aboy [Why are symbols not written in words?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277281/)

Comment: The rendered view of MathJax/LaTeX code is very good, but latex code is bad, so I want to just render Sagemath code directly

Comment: @aboy Remember that you are writing this question not for yourself , but for the *community* to read . Hence you should set aside your preference and try to write it in a way that most people are comfortable with . $($ Which in this case is $\LaTeX$ .$)$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380962/how-to-approximately-compute-the-infinite-sum-of-inverses-of-products-of-consecu

Comment: How is the basel problem related to your question?

Comment: yes, /questions/2380962 asked the same series's value before two years ago, but he wrote as $ S = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_i p_{i+1}} $ . it's not clear. And, no one answered what does the sum converge to.

Comment: I see no reason to believe that there is a closed-form expression for this sum.

Comment: No, /questions/2380962 doesn't ask about the same series. It asks about $$\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 5}+\frac{1}{5\cdot 7}+\frac{1}{7\cdot 11}+\frac{1}{11\cdot 13}+ \dots$$but you can use the same techniques shown there to bound your sum.

Answer (score 1):

For $n>1$:
$$p_n \ge 2n-1,$$
(strong inequality for $n>4$),
so we can estimate upper bound for the series
$$
S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{p_{2k-1}p_{2k}}\tag{1}
$$
this way: for some $K \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$ S <  \sum_{k=1}^{K}\dfrac{1}{p_{2k-1}p_{2k}} + \sum_{k=K+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(4k-3)(4k-1)}
$$
$$ =  \sum_{k=1}^{K}\dfrac{1}{p_{2k-1}p_{2k}} + \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(4k-3)(4k-1)} } - \sum_{k=1}^{K}\dfrac{1}{(4k-3)(4k-1)}
$$
$$
= \color{blue}{\dfrac{\pi}{8}} + \sum_{k=1}^{K}\dfrac{1}{p_{2k-1}p_{2k}} - \sum_{k=1}^{K}\dfrac{1}{(4k-3)(4k-1)}.\tag{2}
$$

For $K=20$ we have:
$$S < 
 \color{blue}{0.392699...}
            + 0.209968...
            - 0.389574...
\approx
0.213092...$$
which is (essentially) less than $16/75\approx0.213333...$ .

For $K=100$ we'll have better/closer upper bound: $S < 0.211000...$;

 for $K=1000$ we have: $S < 0.210485...$;

 for $K=10000$ we have: $S < 0.210431...$ .

---

Lower bound could be estimated simply via any partial sum:
$$
S > \sum_{k=1}^{10000}\dfrac{1}{p_{2k-1}p_{2k}} \approx 0.210425...
$$

So, finally:
$$
0.21042 < S < 0.21044.
$$

---

(more precise value: $S = 0.21042575...$)